# how to let sympy.sympify use predefined symbols?

Tags: python, sympy

it is easy to understand that

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x', real=True)

y = sin(x)
dy = y.diff(x)
ddy = y.diff(x, 2)

print(y.subs(x, pi/2), dy.subs(x, pi/2), ddy.subs(x, pi/2), )
```

will output `1 0 -1`

now if the expression of y is not pre-defined but required to be input by user, for example

```
y = input('please input expression about x: ')
y = sympify(y)
dy = y.diff(x)
ddy = y.diff(x, 2)
```

but if the user input `sin(x)` again,

```
print(y.subs(x, pi/2), dy.subs(x, pi/2), ddy.subs(x, pi/2), )
```

says

```
sin(x) 0 0
```

and

```
print(y.subs('x', pi/2), dy.subs('x', pi/2), ddy.subs('x', pi/2), )
```

says

```
1 0 0
```

so sympify does not know `x` as a symbol like what `sympy.sin(x)` does. So how can we fix it? thanks

Comment: I found that `dy = y.diff('x')` then `dy.subs('x', pi/2)` works. But if I want to pre-define some functions in my source, I still prefer to a consistent and concise python expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why there is a parameter `locals` in [`sympify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.sympify.sympify):

```
y = sympify(y, locals={'x': x})
```

This would not be necessary if your `x` did not have the assumption `real=True`. Symbols are considered the same if they have the same attributes: name and assumptions. A symbol obtained from the string `sin(x)` has no assumptions to it such as being real. So the 
 name matches your `x` but assumptions do not.

Another approach is to not restrict the user to the variable name being `x`; just use whatever symbol they used.

```
y = sympify(y)
x = next(iter(y.free_symbols))  # get the first (and hopefully only) symbol in the formula
dy = y.diff(x)
# and so on
```